# Check if there is a common substring in two strings using BIT Manipulation

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, substring

The following code is used to check if two strings have a common sub-string and print YES if there is a common substring , NO if there is no common substring.
What does the line No:7 exactly do? Please explain.

```
    1     #include<iostream>
    2     using namespace std;
    3    
    4     int letterBits(const string &s) {
    5        int bits = 0;
    6        for (char ch : s)
    7            bits |= 1 << (ch - 'a');
    8        return bits;
   10     }
   11     
   12     int main() {
   13         int testCases;
   14         cin >> testCases;
   15         while (testCases--) {
   16             string strA, strB;
   17             cin >> strA >> strB;
   18             int bitsA = letterBits(strA);
   19             
   20             int bitsB = letterBits(strB);
   21             cout<<bitsB<<" ";
   22             cout << (bitsA & bitsB ? "YES": "NO") << endl;
   23         }
   24         return 0;
   25     }
```

Comment: Woe betide anyone who inputs a string that produces a negative or overly large result for `(ch - 'a')`... this is just not a good technique.

Comment: Thank you for the nice formatting and line numbers. +1

Comment: Reminder, in the semantics of line 7 the `<<` operator is *left-shift*, not stream insertion.

Answer (score 1):

line 7 is setting a bit in the integer bits for each letter it finds.  (e.g. set bit 0 if the letter is 'a', bit 1 if letter is 'b' etc).

This method only checks to see if the 2 strings have the same letters, so "abc"=="cba".

Comment: Actually, it checks whether the two strings have at least one letter in common, which I suppose is another way of phrasing "have a common substring". The answer would be YES for, say, "abc" and "axy".

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  so irrespective of the order of occurence of the letters ,  it just finds if there is a common  character ?

Comment: @Indhuja Why don't you test it and confirm for yourself?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I think you are wrong there.  Line 6 is a foreach over the whole string.  "abc" would set bits 0,1,2 (making the value 7) and "axy" would set bits 0, 25 & 26 (making value 100663297), therefore the strings are not equal.

Comment: One other thing to know is that this will only work for lower case letters.  If you supply for example "ABC", then 'A'-'a' => 65 - 97 =  -32.  I haven't checked, but 1<<-32 is probably undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Neil `(7 & 100663297) != 0` . That's what line 22 checks for. (For the record, `'x'` and `'y'` correspond to bits 23 and 24; that's largely beside the point though).

Comment: @Neil this will work for both upper and lower cases :
bits |= 1 << (abs(ch - 'a'));